# Save pdf file on device

Tags: android, android-studio, pdf, itext

I am working on filling a pdf form and save it into the device but the first catch returns this: "FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/myFile.pdf: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)". Even though I added a checkPermission function to my code.

This is my code :

```
checkPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 101);
checkPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 101);

                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/myFile.pdf");

                try {
                    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.bail_1));

                    try {
                        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(new FileOutputStream(file));
                        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);

                        pdf.close();
                        writer.close();

                        Toast.makeText(this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(this,"FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show;
                        return;

                    }

                    reader.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(this,"FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show; 
                    return;
                }

                
    private void checkPermission(String permission, int requestCode) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Version of Android device>

Comment: `Toast.makeText(this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` You have two catch block above that line. Even if there is a catch you toast  "OK". You should place Toasts in the catch blocks and then return if there is a catch. Please adapt your code. Also here.

Comment: Also a `writer.close();` is missing.

Comment: @blackapps I have edited my code, I don't know if I understand it well but ERROR 1 appears so does it means that there is a problem with PdfWriter ?

Comment: My device is Pixel 2 API 30

Comment: `Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` Such a message does tell the user nothing. And you are still continuing instead of returning. Better: `Toast.makeText(this, "FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); return;`. Do the same with the IOEXception. Please adapt your code.

Comment: `There is no error but.....` Please adapt your post too. After that we can remove comments.

Comment: `And I also added this to my manifest :` And runtime permissions?

Answer (score 0):

```
   this is not just regarding the reader issue
   it may be about the path.....change your code to this and check
// change your path receiving line to   
    File file = new File(getFilePath("myFile.pdf"));

//and Path getting Function
private String getFilePath(String pdfName) {
           ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new 
                          ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
       File fileDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
       File pdfFile = new File (fileDir, pdfName);
       return pdfFile.getPath();
}
//Old Conventional ways do not work in some cases
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).